# Setting values to a filtered excel range in vba

Tags: vba, range, filtering

I have some VBA code that I wrote to apply filters from multiple columns one-by-one to set a flag "X" in another column based on selections made with another script. I have about a dozen columns that could have a flag set for each row. If any flag is set AND the set of filter criteria includes the column header, then I set a flag in a Column 'Applies'.

I can do this cell by cell, but it takes about 5 seconds to run for about 160 rows, so it's not very efficient. To improve the speed, I thought I'd try using ranges and filtering to set all values in the filtered set. Here's the relevant code:

```
Sub ApplySelections2()
'
'   ApplySelections Macro
'       This macro applies the selections in the Project Technology block
'       This version uses column filtering instead of testing each cell
'

'   Turn off screen updates
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim StTime, DeltaT As Double
    StTime = Timer

'   Remove active Filters

    If ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then

'       Filtering is on
'        MsgBox ("Filtering on")
        ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    End If

    Dim ItemLocCol, ItemLocRow, AppliesLocCol, FilterLocCol, ItemLen, FilterLen As Integer
    Dim FltHdrRng, AppRng, ItemFltRng, ListRng As Range
    Dim TypFound, ProjStr, TestStr As String
    Dim x As Integer

' Get Locations and ranges of data

    Application.Goto Reference:="ProjectTechnology"
    ProjStr = Selection.Value
    Application.Goto Reference:="ItemNo"
    ItemLocCol = Selection.Column
    ItemLocRow = Selection.Row
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    ItemLen = Selection.Cells.Count - 1
    Application.Goto Reference:="Applies"
    AppliesLocCol = Selection.Column

    Application.Goto Reference:="StartFilters"
    FilterLocCol = Selection.Column
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Set FltHdrRng = Selection
    FilterLen = Selection.Count

'   Select Applies Column

    Cells(ItemLocRow + 1, AppliesLocCol).Select
    Range(Selection, Cells(ItemLocRow + ItemLen - 1, AppliesLocCol)).Select
    Set AppRng = Selection

'   Clear Applies Cell range

    AppRng.Value = ""

'   I'll clean this up by automating the range selection later

    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$9:$AA$169").Select
    Set ListRng = Selection

'   Apply filters based on each cell in header range

    For Each Cell In FltHdrRng
        x = Cell.Column
        If InStr(ProjStr, Cell.Value) Then
        ' Header Technology used in project
            ListRng.AutoFilter Field:=x, Criteria1:="<>"
            AppRng.Visible.Value = "X"
            ListRng.AutoFilter Field:=x
            AppRng.Value = "X"
         End If
    Next Cell

'   show elapsed time
    DeltaT = Timer - StTime
    MsgBox ("Elapsed Time: " + Str(DeltaT) + " Seconds")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

The For Each Cell code works on the initial pass when I step through it. That is, it properly filters and sets the values in AppRng that are visible after the filter is applied to ListRng. However, the next matching value in FltHdrRng appears to filter correctly, but this time the statement AppRng.Value = "X", sets all values in the range to "X", whether visible or not.